# SQL Tables: Can I Pivot/Join with N rows?

Tags: sql, database, datagrid, pivot-table

First, I am a SQL noob, second if there is a better solution that can be implement in code later, I'd love to hear it. Also, the data is currently stored in MySQL but will eventually have to be ported to MSSQL so a cross DB solution would be best (if one exists).

Now, the problem, my simplified data looks like this:

```
[STYLES]
ID   NAME
1    A Style
2    B Style
...
N    N Style

[EQUIPMENT]
ID   NAME
1    A Equipment
2    B Equipment
...
N    N Equipment

[AVAILABILITY]
STYLE  EQUIPMENT  TYPE
1      1          Standard
1      2          Optional
2      1          Optional
... #items will be missing and represent not available
2      2          Standard
```

Now I need a table that looks like this:

```
[DESIRED_VIEW]
EQUIPMENT_NAME   A_STYLE_TYPE  B_STYLE_TYPE ... N_STYLE_TYPE
A Equipment      Standard      Optional     ... NULL
B Equipment      Optional      NULL         ... Standard
```

I have seen a number of simple pivot examples and they all rely on having a set number of columns. Is there a way to set up the view with a variable number of columns based on how many rows are in the STYLES table?

As a note, I am using Visual Studio to create the Data xsd and letting it auto-generate the table fill methods then displaying the info in WPF DataGrids so being able to bind directly to a view with the correct data would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - there is no way to write a query that has a dynamic number of columns.

Your choices are (in order of preference):

1. write a query that has "a lot" of columns, some of which may be blank (easy to write and use, but there would be a hard maximum on the pivot width)
2. write app code that writes the dynamic query for you (not too bad: portable)
3. write a stored procedure to create the SQL (terrible choice: painful to write logic code in PL/SQL and totally non-portable)

If you are comfortable with a maximum number of styles (it can be arbitrarily large, but finite), code your pivot would look like this:

```
select
  e.name as equipment_name,
  a1.type as a_style_type,
  a2.type as b_style_type,
  a3.type as c_style_type,
  ...
  an.type as n_style_type
from equipment e
left join availability a1 on a1.equipment = e.id and a1.style = 1
left join availability a2 on a2.equipment = e.id and a2.style = 2
left join availability a3 on a3.equipment = e.id and a3.style = 3
...
left join availability an on an.equipment = e.id and an.style = 999;
```

When there is no availability type for a given style, you'll get a `NULL`.

Also, you need to know the style ids and they need to be the same on all environemtns. If this is not the case (eg different in test/prod environments) you can change `a1.style = 1` to `a1.style = (select id from style where name = 'A Style')` etc - it will still perform OK.

Comment: MS-SQL uses T-SQL, not PL/SQL. Apart from that, one non-portable stored-procedure can be rewritten for the target system - but certainly a point to consider when doing it often. And complicated queries are almost never portable.

Comment: I followed number 2 above using code to build up the select using the same syntax you provided, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only when using dynamic SQL (stored procedure).
Here an example in real-life usage

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[sp_RPT_Report_Translation]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RPT_Report_Translation]
GO







-- ===========================================================
-- Author:        [CENSORED]
-- Create date:   14.04.2011
-- Last modified: 17.01.2012
-- Description:   Übersetzung für Berichte
-- ===========================================================
-- Pre: Valid Report Name & datetime
-- Post: Translation for language in first row with rownames as defined 
--       for each item in T_RPT_Translations.RTR_ItemCaption
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RPT_Report_Translation]
     @in_mandant varchar(3) 
    ,@in_sprache varchar(2) 
    ,@in_stichtag varchar(50) 
    ,@in_report_name nvarchar(1000) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
     @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    ,@strReportName NVARCHAR(1000) 
    ,@strPivotColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    ,@stichtag DATETIME 


    -- Abrunden des Eingabedatums auf 00:00:00 Uhr 
    SET @stichtag    = CONVERT(DATETIME, @in_stichtag) 
    SET @stichtag    = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@stichtag AS Float)) AS DateTime) 
    SET @in_stichtag = CONVERT(varchar(50), @stichtag) 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @strReportName = REPLACE(@in_report_name, N'''', '''''') 

    -- http://geekswithblogs.net/baskibv/archive/2008/07/03/123567.aspx
    SELECT 
        @strPivotColumns = COALESCE(@strPivotColumns, '') + '[' + [RTR_ItemCaption] + '], ' 
    FROM T_RPT_Translations 
    WHERE (RTR_Status = 1) 
        AND (RTR_MDT_ID = @in_mandant) 
        AND 
        ( 
            (RTR_ReportName = @strReportName) 
            OR 
            (RTR_ReportName = 'PARA_ALL') 
        ) 
        --AND (RTR_ItemCaption != 'RPT_Title') 
        AND (RTR_ItemCaption IS NOT NULL) 
        AND 
        (
                (RTR_IsFlag != 1) 
                OR 
                (RTR_IsFlag IS NULL) 
        ) 
        AND (RTR_ItemCaption != '') 
    ORDER BY RTR_Sort



    SET @strPivotColumns = SUBSTRING(@strPivotColumns, 0, LEN(@strPivotColumns)) 
    SET @strPivotColumns = REPLACE(@strPivotColumns, N'''', '''''') 

    --PRINT @strPivotColumns

    SET @strSQL = '
        SELECT TOP(1) * FROM 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                 RTR_ItemCaption 
                --,RTR_Kurz_' + @in_sprache + ' 
                ,RTR_Lang_' + @in_sprache + ' 
            FROM T_RPT_Translations 
            WHERE (RTR_MDT_ID = ''' + @in_mandant+ ''') 
                AND
                ( 
                    (RTR_ReportName = ''' + @strReportName + ''') 
                    OR 
                    (RTR_ReportName = ''PARA_ALL'')
                )
                --AND (RTR_ItemCaption != ''RPT_Title'') 
                AND (RTR_Status = 1) 
                AND (RTR_ItemCaption IS NOT NULL)
                AND 
                (
                    (RTR_IsFlag != 1) 
                    OR 
                    (RTR_IsFlag IS NULL) 
                ) 
                AND (RTR_ItemCaption != '''')  

        ) AS SourceTable 
        PIVOT 
        ( 
            MAX(RTR_Lang_' + @in_sprache + ') 
            FOR RTR_ItemCaption IN 
            ( ' 
                + @strPivotColumns + 
          ' ) 

        ) AS PivotTable 

        --ORDER BY RPT_RM_SO_Bezeichnung, RPT_RM_GB_Bezeichnung, RPT_RM_NutzungGruppeCode 
    ' 

    DECLARE @ProzedurParameter nvarchar(max)
    SET @ProzedurParameter = '
    DECLARE @in_mandant varchar(3) 
    ,@in_sprache varchar(2) 
    ,@in_stichtag varchar(50) 
    ,@in_report_name nvarchar(1000) 
    ;

    SET @in_mandant = ''' + REPLACE(@in_mandant, '''', '''''') + '''; 
    SET @in_sprache = ''' + REPLACE(@in_sprache, '''', '''''') + '''; 
    SET @in_stichtag = ''' + REPLACE(@in_stichtag, '''', '''''') + '''; 
    SET @in_report_name = ''' + REPLACE(@in_report_name, '''', '''''') + '''; 
    '



    EXECUTE sp_RPT_DEBUG_LOG_ProzedurRun 
        'sp_RPT_Report_Translation'
        ,@ProzedurParameter
        ,@strSQL 
        ,'' --@ProzedurDetail
    ;


    --PRINT @strSQL
    EXECUTE (@strSQL)

END



GO
```

The table for this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations](
    [RTR_UID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [RTR_ReportName] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [RTR_MDT_ID] [int] NULL,
    [RTR_ItemCaption] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RTR_Code] [int] NULL,
    [RTR_nCode] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RTR_Kurz_DE] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [RTR_Kurz_FR] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [RTR_Kurz_IT] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [RTR_Kurz_EN] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [RTR_Lang_DE] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RTR_Lang_FR] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RTR_Lang_IT] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RTR_Lang_EN] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [RTR_Img_DE] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RTR_Img_FR] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RTR_Img_IT] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RTR_Img_EN] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RTR_Img_Width] [int] NULL,
    [RTR_Img_Height] [int] NULL,
    [RTR_Img_PaddingLeft] [float] NULL,
    [RTR_Img_PaddingRight] [float] NULL,
    [RTR_Img_PaddingTop] [float] NULL,
    [RTR_Img_PaddingBottom] [float] NULL,
    [RTR_Img_Hide] [bit] NULL,
    [RTR_IsLogo] [bit] NULL,
    [RTR_IsFlag] [bit] NULL,
    [RTR_Sort] [int] NULL,
    [RTR_Status] [int] NULL,
    [RTR_DatumVon] [datetime] NULL,
    [RTR_DatumBis] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_T_RPT_Translations_RTR_UID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [RTR_UID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_T_RPT_Translations_RTR_ReportName]  DEFAULT (N'InsertError') FOR [RTR_ReportName]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_T_RPT_Translations_RTR_MDT_ID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RTR_MDT_ID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_T_RPT_Translations_RTR_ItemCaption]  DEFAULT (N'InsertError') FOR [RTR_ItemCaption]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_T_RPT_Translations_RTR_IsLogo]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RTR_IsLogo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_T_RPT_Translations_RTR_IsFlag]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RTR_IsFlag]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_T_RPT_Translations_RTR_Sort]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RTR_Sort]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_T_RPT_Translations_RTR_Status]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [RTR_Status]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_T_RPT_Translations_RTR_DatumVon]  DEFAULT ('17530101') FOR [RTR_DatumVon]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_RPT_Translations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_T_RPT_Translations_RTR_DatumBis]  DEFAULT ('99991231') FOR [RTR_DatumBis]
GO
```

In case you don't understand the parameters, which are in german:

```
@in_sprache: in_language
@in_stichtag: in_ReportingDate
DatumVon: DateFrom
DatumBis: DateTo
rest is clear
```

RTR_Img_XX is an image base64-encoded, with mime defined in RTR_nCode, in case you wonder.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, as I said, I'm still new to SQL in general and your answer has quite a lot of overhead more me to sift through (including comments in german?) so it will take me some time to try to apply it to my own case.

Comment: Take a look at the geekswithblogs link in a commented-out line of the stored procedure, it explains the coalesce use. The only comment in German is "-- Abrunden des Eingabedatums auf 00:00:00 Uhr", which means round down the input date (in_stichtag) to 0 o'clock, so you don't get a datetime with time (as in DateTime.Now) and compare it with a datetime without time (same day, but 0 o'clock - you know 31.12.2011 00:00 < 31.12.2011 15:00). For everything else: http://www.google.com/translate